# how to set upgrade-insecur-requests based on nginx

Tags: google-chrome, nginx, https

I have changed my site to `https`,but I used the cdn of static files in the code. it can't work and the chrome console show the errors like this:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://a.example.com/static/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

I have add the `add_header Content-Security-Policy upgrade-insecure-requests;` in the nginx configuration file like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443;
    server_name a.example.com;
    add_header Content-Security-Policy upgrade-insecure-requests;

    if ($scheme != "https") {
       return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
       #rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
    }


    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/example.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.key;

    ssl_session_timeout 5m;

    ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers "HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5 or HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!3DES";
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    gzip on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types text/plain application/xml application/json;
    client_max_body_size 8M;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/example.log;
    location / {
            proxy_pass http://10.10.10.110:5000;
            proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
    location ^~ /static/ {

            proxy_pass http://10.10.10.110:8888;
            proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
           #proxy_set_header Content-Security-Policy upgrade-insecure-requests;
    }
```

}

but it does't work yet! Can someone tell me how to fix this? thx :)

Comment: here is my chrome and nginx version`chrome`:`51.0.2704.84 (64-bit)`
`nginx`:`1.4.6 ubuntu`

Answer (score 4):

Be aware that `upgrade-insecure-requests` is [not supported in all browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=upgradeinsecurerequests), e.g. Safari and IE.

I recommend that you just replace the HTTP requests in your code. You can use  `//` to load it relative to the protocol it is called from as per:

```
//cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

That means that if you are opening the web application from an HTTPS context, it will load it using the HTTPS protocol, otherwise it will use HTTP.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who comes across this and wants a better way that is guarunteed to work in all browsers (though everything should in theory support it now, other than IE)

The included files are just where you'd have your standard nginx setup that you'd reuse across each server and tls is all the "ssl" config which you just setup the way you want.

Anything that goes to port 80 is perminantly redirected to the HTTPS Site, you can also add the content-security-policy, which if you have any unsecure links will make sure the browser if it supports it directly goes to the https url preventing it making an extra request to the http site and then being redirected

This config also redirects base domain requests to www. so that you can easily setup cookieless domains for static content (just add another config similar to the last one but for like static.example.com)

Should in theory be more efficient having seperated configs that way the base domain and port 80 configs are specialised for their tasks and less processing has to be done on the main website to account for those scenarios.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    include /etc/nginx/common/defaults.conf;

    add_header Content-Security-Policy upgrade-insecure-requests;

    location / {
        return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name example.com;
    include /etc/nginx/common/defaults.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/common/tls_modern.conf;

    add_header Content-Security-Policy upgrade-insecure-requests;

    location / {
        return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name www.example.com 127.0.0.1 localhost;
    include /etc/nginx/common/defaults.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/common/tls_modern.conf;

    add_header Content-Security-Policy upgrade-insecure-requests;
    
    index index.html;
    try_files /index.html =404;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/www;
    }
}
```